# Angular 17 List ? chaining operator in template Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: angular

So I've written a component that is getting an array or null as an input (to be async pipe compatible) though my getter and backing field can never return null, as this is handled by the ?? operator in the setter.

```
  @Input()
  public set items(values: T[] | null) {
    this._items = values ?? [];
  }

  public get items() {
    return this._items;
  }

  private _items: T[] = [];
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmVjo.png)

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/generic-items-list-if-should-cannot-be-null?file=src%2Fmain.ts

I tried chaining with the ? operator which results in object can be undefined and i tried to get rid of the T type. Both times the issue is persisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the template.

Try this out:

```
@if(items?.length){
  <p>items are availlable</p>
}
```

It is because the `accesors` (`set` and `get` have the same argument/retun type), therefore having this:

```
  public set items(values: T[] | null) {
    this._items = values ?? [];
  }

  public get items() {
    return this._items;
  }
```

the `get` will return `T[] | null` type.

**Wrapping up:**

if you change the argument type of the `set` from `T[] | null` to `T[]` everything will work safely at runtime since every `nullish` value is escaped by this `this._items = values ?? []`. Your final code could be like this:

Component:

```
export class GenericTableComponent<T = unknown> {
  @Input()
  public set items(values: T[]) {
    this._items = values ?? [];
  }

  public get items() {
    return this._items;
  }

  private _items: T[] = [];
}
```

And its template:

```
@if(items.length){
  <p>items are availlable</p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems I can see are.

1. You have not provided a value for `items` in main.ts

Before:

```
<app-generic-table [items]=/>
```

After:

```
<app-generic-table [items]="[]"/>
```

2. The length property can throw an error when the value of `items` is `undefined` so you are getting that error, since there is no return type specified for the getter method, typescript assumes the type as `T[] or undefined`, you can change the getter to `T[]` to inform typescript that there will always be an array present. As a safety I added a or condition where if its falsy, then an empty array will be returned!

code

```
public get items(): T[] { // <- changed here
    return this._items || [];
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/generic-items-list-if-should-cannot-be-null-xjrnbp?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fgeneric-table%2Fgeneric-table.component.html,src%2Fgeneric-table%2Fgeneric-table.component.ts)